# Rails , is it possible use SSL partially

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to use http for some request and https for other requests for one rails server like

```
http://i.mysite.com/
```

and

```
https://mysite.com/
```

THanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
before_filter :https_redirect

def https_redirect
  if request.ssl? && !use_https? || !request.ssl? && use_https?
    protocol = request.ssl? ? "http" : "https"
    flash.keep
    redirect_to protocol: "#{protocol}://", status: :moved_permanently
  end
end

def use_https?
  controller_name == "abc"
end
```

(I take this code from some place, I don't remember so I can't give the credits... but I use it on a project and it works).

UPDATE: I take the code from a RailsCasts haha so thanks to Ryan Bates.