# skip/disable force_ssl for particular controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl

I need to force SSL on all routes in my application except for `message#new` controller.

In `config/environments/production.rb`, I have:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Now all routes being redirect to https, And now I want to disable that for `message#new` controller.

Does anyone know how to disable force SSL for particular controller in a Rails 4+ application?

Comment: Why do you need to disable SSL for every route except one?  Considering that it [makes use of HSTS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17785434/1079354), the likelihood of being able to selectively allow one route to communicate insecurely is *slim*.

Comment: in that controller i get response from third party url, its not receiving, so I want to disable ssl for that particular controller only

Comment: Why not investigate why the third-party URL is broken?  Do you get a specific error code back?

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this? The closest I've found is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700182/rails-force-ssl-only-on-specified-controllers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962221/rails-is-it-possible-use-ssl-partially which are both non-DRY ways of the opposite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
force_ssl except: [:index,:create]
```

Its worked for me.

Comment: DEPRECATION WARNING: Controller-level `force_ssl` is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1. Please enable `config.force_ssl` in your environment configuration to enable the ActionDispatch::SSL middleware to more fully enforce that your application communicate over HTTPS. If needed, you can use `config.ssl_options` to exempt matching endpoints from being redirected to HTTPS.

Answer (score 34):

according to [documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/SSL.html) following should work (**but only for rails > 5 version**):

```
config.ssl_options = {
  redirect: {
    exclude: -> request { request.path =~ /healthcheck/ }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but never actually been able to get it to work.  have you actually tried this?

Comment: @Lorenz yes, I have tried this and it worked. If for some reason it doesn't work (rails version <5, forgotten rails server restart, incorrect code placement?) there are a lot of stuff could happen, even it's broken in recent rails versions. In any case it's copy/paste from official docs, so it should work, if not, than rails issue tracker is probably better place for discussions

Comment: yeah, I was trying to get it to exclude particular subdomains and it wasn't working.  Running rails 5.1.  This is the line: config.ssl_options = { redirect: { exclude: -> (request) { return true if ((request.subdomain =~ /mail|link|blog|slab/) != nil) } } }

Answer (score -2):

Do this in `MessagesController.rb` -

```
  force_ssl except: [:new]
```

Comment: This is doesn't work because `config.force_ssl` is working on middleware level so HTTP requests never hit controllers.