# Forcing ssl on devise controller redirects to GET instead of DELETE on sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https, devise

I've placed `config.to_prepare { Devise::SessionsController.force_ssl }` in my `production.rb` in order to require logging in/out via https.

Unfortunately, `force_ssl` seems to forget the original request method. Logs:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for (...)
Processing by Users::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"foo"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = id  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to https://my.domain/users/sign_out
Filter chain halted as #<Proc:some-ruby-path/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_controller/metal/force_ssl.rb:65> rendered or redirected

Completed 301 Moved Permanently in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for (...)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out")
```

Any ideas how to tackle this? It seems like it could be a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 private

 # Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
 def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   root_path
 end
end
```

From the [Devise docs for signout](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out), just change **root_path** to **root_path :protocol => 'http://'**. Once you signout, return it to some page.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the issue, the `destroy` isn't called at all. After redirecting to `https` it tries to call `destroy` with a GET method instead of DELETE.

Comment: You cannot use redirect_to with Delete method, it just gets the destination url

Comment: Also apart from devise are you using any authentication/authorization gems

Answer (score -1):

That worked for me (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38821571/787475)) :

```
config.to_prepare { Devise::SessionsController.force_ssl except: [:destroy] }
```

This way, SSL redirection is not necessary for loging out.