# Force SSL exception for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, https, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm working on a specific case where I want to force SSL in a Rails app, I've tried using:

```
Rails.application.configure do
    config.force_ssl = true
end
```

However, there are a couple of endpoints that load content from 3rd party websites using iframes and I'm getting a `Content-Mixed error` because some of them don't support HTTPS.

Is there a way to mark certain routes as exempt to the `force_ssl` config in Rails?

Working on a Rails 4.1.x app, thanks!

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421977/skip-disable-force-ssl-for-particular-controller-in-rails) answer your question? It looks very similar.

Comment: Note the potentially rails 5-specific accepted answer, and also the one below...