# Disable force_ssl for specific controllers in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I added  *force_ssl*  to my production.rb:

```
  config.force_ssl = true
```

But now I want to disable SSL for some of my controllers. I tried to add to my controllers:

```
before_action :force_no_ssl
```

but it gives me an:

**undefined method `force_no_ssl' for PagesController:0x4a29560**

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Where did you find that `force_no_ssl`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [skip/disable force\_ssl for particular controller in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421977/skip-disable-force-ssl-for-particular-controller-in-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the global configuration method.  This ensures ssl on every controller and every action.  Switch to controller based forcing.

You can either add it to every controller you want it in, or add it to the application controller and turn it off based on the controller/action combo, i like a case statement because it allows multiple options, but you can do what works best for your app.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  force_ssl unless: :no_ssl?

  def no_ssl?
    case "#{params[:controller]} #{params[:action]}"
    when "parents index"
      return false
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to that from above posted by *trh*:

```
def force_no_ssl
  if request.ssl? && is_production?
    redirect_to :protocol => 'http://', :status => :moved_permanently
  end
end
```

where I then add to all the controllers that should use *http*:

```
before_action :force_no_ssl
```